# Существуют книги/ресурсы, в которых указано, как создавать сложные сайты с обращением к базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Под сложными сайтами я подразумеваю сайты, в которых есть регистрация, авторизация, личный кабинет, отдельное окно для вопросов/ответов/товара, чего угодно.

Comment: В книгах, как правило, дается общий подход, без конкретных примеров, а на сайтах - однобразные и порой примитивные примеры по реализации того или иного компонента, или использования фреймворка. Так что придется прочитать не одну книгу и перелопатить гору материала, чтобы что-то понять, сделать выводы и т.д. С миру по нитке, как говорится.

Comment: @zhenyab, верно глаголишь!  
@Forigin, я изучал и изучаю именно на практике. В книгах теоретические рекомендации даны, изучение примеров порой даёт неожиданный результат - полный новичок, казалось бы, напишет лучше, видимо автору статьи недостаточно заплатили, вот и халтурит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В книгах такого вряд ли пишут, а если и пишут, то на практике это применять явно не стоит.

Но вот люди это создающие опытом делятся и [конференции](http://www.highload.ru/) проводят.

В сети можно поискать ресурсы с различными видео от профессионалов, например:

- [видео с конференций highload](https://vimeo.com/ontico/videos)
- [технопарк MailRu](https://www.youtube.com/user/TPMGTU/videos)
- [видео про WordPress](http://wordpress.tv/)
- etc

В этих видео может и не сказано как создать ту же регистрацию/личный кабинет и т.д., но зато много материала по защите, сопровождению, масштабированию, отказоустойчивости и т.д., без которого действительно сложные и хорошие сайты (и не только сайты) не создать

Answer (score 1):

Есть хороший ресурс, хотя скорее это каталог этих книг и ресурсов:
[Тут!](http://google.com/)
P. S. Какой вопрос - такой ответ.